# Java 9 Modularity exports is not working

Tags: java, java-9

I'm trying to learn java 9 modularity.

In my project I have 3 modules -
1. com.red30tech.database
2. com.red30tech.cache
3. com.red30tech.backend.

1 is  depend on 2, 3 and 2 is depend on 3.

The source code of the project is [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/Exercise1).

when I try to compile the project I get below error.

```
Exercise1> javac -d mods/ --module-source-path src $(find src -name "*.java")
src/com.red30tech.backend/com/red30tech/backend/Processor.java:10: error: package com.red30tech.cache does not exist
            db = com.red30tech.cache.api.Cache(db);
                                        ^
1 error
```

If I comment this [line](https://github.com/rajcspsg/Exercise1/blob/master/src/com.red30tech.backend/com/red30tech/backend/Processor.java#L10), then the compilation is successful.

I've exported the package in module cache [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/Exercise1/blob/master/src/com.red30tech.cache/module-info.java#L3) and added the requires in backend module [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/Exercise1/blob/master/src/com.red30tech.backend/module-info.java#L3).

Any reason why my package is not recognized in backend module?

Comment: Please update the question with respective code lines to make it an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's really poor to navigate to all those links to see what the construct is and then debug if required.

Comment: Change it to `new db = com.red30tech.cache.api.Cache(db)` and I assume it will compile. I agree the error message from `javac` is confusing in this case.

Comment: @AlanBateman I guess you mean  `db = new com.red30tech.cache.api.Cache(db)`?

Comment: Yes, I he's missing `new` which makes it looks like it's a static method on class api, hence the apparently misleading message from javac.

Comment: indeed I did a dumb mistake I'm missing `new` while creating object :(. I will close this question